# Select numbers or data from PHP array

Tags: php, sql

The SQL code to get data from SQL. This will show user's earnings (referrals). I will add (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY / something later, now lets keep it simple.

```
/ Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT username,COUNT(*)
FROM earnings
GROUP BY day(date)";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

print_r($row);
        }
```

The following is the `PHP` array result I got from `SQL`.

```
Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => 3 [COUNT(*)] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => 1 [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => 1 [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => 3 [COUNT(*)] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => 12 [COUNT(*)] => 12 )
```

If I want to get the number "12" in a `php` string, what should I do ?

In short the array is generated differently for each user according to database data.
You can see the last number in each line of the array (3,1,1,3 and 12), these are the only useful numbers.
I want to use them as $something[0], $something[1] etc..
for example
echo $something[0]; should display "3"
and
echo $something[1]; should display "1
and"
echo $something[4]; should display "12"

Comment: Give that result an alias then you can access like any other column identifier

Comment: @John Conde, can you show me an example ? I am new to coding!

Comment: `SELECT username,COUNT(*) AS earning_count `

Comment: @John Conde, that replaced the `[COUNT(*)]` with `[earning_count]`, but still I dont know how to get each number in separate php string.

Comment: `echo $row['earning_count']`;

Comment: Your query looks wrong. you need to add `username` field into `GROUP BY` statement like :`SELECT username,COUNT(*)
FROM earnings
GROUP BY username, day(date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_push https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php like this

```
$sql = "SELECT username,COUNT(*) as earningcount
        FROM earnings
        GROUP BY day(date)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$something = [];

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     array_push($something,$row['earningcount']);
   }
}

// You can now use this variable $something;
echo $something[0];
echo $something[1];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$something' (T_VARIABLE),  "$something = [];" is causing error!

Comment: Sorry I forgot the `;` on end of the line for this `$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)` I will edit it.